# How can I use the google maps API with a currently-valid version?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got an app that incorporates google maps. I call in the library with:

src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=[VERSION]&key=[MYKEY]&sensor=false"

It ran OK for a year or so then one day raised a script error.  I found this was because the version number was out-of-date, so I increased it to the current version.  Then about a year later it happened again.

This time I changed it to 'v=quarterly' which I was told would always use a current stable version.

Today it's crashed again with the script error.  Can anyone tell me how to always invoke a current and stable version of the API?

Many thanks,
Tony Reynolds

Comment: Can you share what the script error was?

Comment: It was:  Error: Script error, Code: 0, URL=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&key=[MYKEY]&sensor=false

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest updating the other parameters you're sending. Google Maps API currently **requires** 2 URL Params:

`key`: Your API key. The Maps JavaScript API will not load unless a valid API key is specified.

`callback`: The name of a global function to be called once the Maps JavaScript API loads completely.

An example of a valid API call would be

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

The version key is not required, and would default to `weekly`, but if you specify `v=quarterly` it will only use larger, less frequent updates.

Also, the sensor parameter is no longer used and is recommended you should remove it.

Sources:
[URL Params](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params),
[Versions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions),
[Sensor Param](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required)